# Does "is" type test with declaration pattern break reference to element in C#

Tags: c#, casting, reference

Let's say I have a function that changes property on an object like this:

```
private void SetTagsInChildren(List<string> tags, Model model)
{
    ContentModel contentModelV1;

    if (model is ContentModel contentModel)
         contentModelV1 = contentModel;

    // Logic to set new tags in model
}
```

Does the declaration of new variable contentModel after the `is` type check (or the assignment that goes after it) break the reference to the original model parameter ? Are the adjustments made on `contentModel` or `contentModelV1` visible on the original model that is passed to the function ?

Comment: if `Model` is a reference type, than all your other variables (`contentModelV1` and `contenModel`) hold the _same_ reference to the _same_ object in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `model` is a *reference type* then `is` performs a reference conversion (if the match is succesful). A reference conversion only converts the static type of the reference (the compile time type of the variable), the runtime objet it is "pointing" to is exactly the same.

Comment: The answer became clearer with each edit :) Thanks!

Comment: @marijuslau yeah, typing on my cell phone is a chore...